# Virtualhost redirect non-existent subdomains

Tags: ssl, https, subdomain, virtualhost

I have a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com` from LetsEncrypt.

I want to catch all non-existent subdomains and redirect them to `example.com`. So everything before example. `sadsdadasdwdasd.example.com => https://example.com`

This works:

```
www.something.example.com => https://example.com
http://www.something.example.com  => https://example.com
https://something.example.com => https://example.com
```

But I have a problem with this: `https://www.something.example.com`

With **www** included I can't redirect this subdomain back to `example.com`, it shows this ssl error: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Because if someone enters `https://www` inside the url, it does not work.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard (`*`) matches only a single lable, not a whole structure.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate:

> Because the wildcard only covers one level of subdomains (the asterisk doesn't match full stops),[4] these domains would not be valid for the certificate:
>
> test.login.example.com

So your certificate for `*.example.com` will never match hostname `www.something.example.com`.  And no, you can not have a certificate for `*.*.example.com`.

Comment: Should I generate a new wildcard certificate for each subdomain?

Comment: @MarkJ. for all names to be served over HTTPS you need a certificate that has a matching name in the list of SNA entries in the certificate sent by the server. A matching name is either the exact name or any wildcard where `*` replaces a single label. So you either need to put each name as is in one or more certificates, or create wildcard for each subdomain indeed, if you can list them. Otherwise your life is more complicated: you need a way to dynamicall generate certificates when the HTTPS request comes which probably means controlling the CA used by clients too.

Comment: So. One wildcard certificate for example.com. And another completely new wildcard certificate for subdomain.example.com. Is this correct?